# Почему преобразование std::optional<int> в std::optional<bool> меняет хранимое значение?

Tags: c++, optional

```
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

int main() {
    const auto a = std::optional<int>(0);
    const auto b = std::optional<bool>(a);

    std::cout << a.value() << b.value() << '\n';
}
```

Почему [программа печатает](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:2,endLineNumber:9,positionColumn:2,positionLineNumber:9,selectionStartColumn:2,selectionStartLineNumber:9,startColumn:2,startLineNumber:9),source:%27%23include+%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include+%3Coptional%3E%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++const+auto+a+%3D+std::optional%3Cint%3E(0)%3B%0A++++const+auto+b+%3D+std::optional%3Cbool%3E(a)%3B%0A%0A++++std::cout+%3C%3C+a.value()+%3C%3C+b.value()+%3C%3C+!%27%5Cn!%27%3B%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g122,deviceViewOpen:%271%27,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,binaryObject:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%270%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Editor+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.333333333333336,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compilerName:%27x86-64+gcc+12.2%27,editorid:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+12.2+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:33.33333333333333,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4) `01`, а не `00`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Потому что при таком преобразовании происходит неявное преобразование `std::optional<int>(0)` в `bool`. А в [документации ясно говорится](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/operator_bool), что такое преобразование дает `true`, если в `std::optional` хранится значение, и `false`, если его нет. Но ведь в `std::optional<int>(0)` значение хранится, с этим вы не спорите? Вот и получается, что его приведение к `bool` дает значение `true`, все в соответствии со стандартом...

Если хотите получить значение, то делайте уж

```
const auto b = std::optional<bool>(*a);
```

только при использовании оператора `*` обратите внимание на примечание

> This operator does not check whether the optional contains a value! You can do so manually by using has_value() or simply operator bool(). Alternatively, if checked access is needed, value() or value_or() may be used.

P.S. Мне показалось правильным внести в ответ из комментариев следующее:

> Если в первом заменить тип `int` на `bool`, то будет ожидаемый вывод. Если поставить в первом `int`, а во втором `double`, то тоже будет ожидаемый результат, хотя при этом типы разные.

Потому что нет оператора преобразования `optional<int>` в `double`, только в `bool`. Соответственно, рассматриваются варианты, требующие более сложного преобразования.
`<bool> -> <bool>` - работает точно соответствующий конструктор копирования.
`<int> -> <bool>` - работает приведение типа к `bool`, о котором я уже написал.
`<int> -> <double>` — ничего проще, чем шаблонный конструктор, нет, применяется он.

Comment: А почему происходит неявное преобразование, а не вызывается конструктор для optional с другим типом, проверяется, есть в нём значение, и копируется значение, если есть? Если в первом заменить тип int на bool, то будет ожидаемый вывод.

Comment: Потому что во втором варианте типы одинаковы, и вызывается копирующий конструктор, а это уже совсем другая история.

Comment: Если поставить в первом int, а во втором double, то тоже будет ожидаемый результат, но при этом типы разные.

Comment: Ну так ведь нет оператора преобразования `optional<int>` в `double`, только в `bool`. Соответственно, рассматриваются варианты, требующие более сложного преобразования. `<bool> -> <bool>` - работает точно соответствующий конструктор копирования. `<int> -> <bool>` - работает приведение типа к `bool`, о котором я написал в ответе. `<int> -> <double>` — ничего проще, чем шаблонный конструктор, нет, применяется он... Общий принцип — используется как можно, скажем так, более простое преобразование. Посмотрите https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional, станет понятнее.